# how can i know that email is real email or not using django framework

Tags: django, email, django-models, django-views, backend

I built an email sender by using the Django framework but the logic that I built it accepted any email whatever is real email or not !!

```
# Sending Email View

def send_email(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SubscribeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = form.cleaned_data['body']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            recipient_list = request.POST['to_email']
            email = EmailMessage(subject, message, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [recipient_list])
            email.send(fail_silently=False)
            messages.success(request, f'email sent to {recipient_list} successfully.')
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = SubscribeForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

**Settings.py**

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
#<<===========================================================================>>
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'MyAccount@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'MyPassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the email is real or not you can use [validate_email](https://pypi.org/project/validate_email/) Python's package.It will check if an email is valid, properly formatted and really exists.

This code will check if the email has an SMTP server and it really exists:

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com',verify=True)
```